# I am having trouble encapsulating the code while using Parser gem to create a static code analyzer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, code-analysis

I am writing a very basic static code analyzer in Ruby. I am using the Parser gem to generate AST and then traversing to ananlyze code. Following is the snippet.

```
class Processor < AST::Processor

  def on_def(node)
    puts node.type
  end

end

parsed_code = Parser::CurrentRuby.parse(some_code) #parsing code to AST
processor = Processor.new
processor.process(parsed_code) #traversing throught the AST
```

Now, the problem is that I can only analyze the code within the class that has processed or traversed the AST. In the above case, that class is the processor class. This means that I will have to implement all my analyze methods within the processor class. But, I don't wanna do that, I want to encapsulate each and every analyzer method in their own class. For instance, like this

```
class CheckIndentation
end

class CheckNamingConvention
end
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

### Define Class/Module Methods with Self

Define a class/module method, rather than an instance method. You do that by explicitly using `self` as the receiver in your method definition so that it refers to the current class/module when the interpreter executes the method definition. For example, the following is untested because your code example was not a complete, verifiable example, but should do what you're trying to accomplish:

```rb
class Processor < AST::Processor
  def self.on_def(node)
    puts node.type
  end
end
```

### See Also

For more complex use cases, it's also worth mentioning the [Module#module_function](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_function) method. This copies instance methods into independent module methods that can call a method with the module/class as the receiver. I mention it here only for completeness; IMHO it's overkill for your specific example.

Comment: In my understanding, the class methods can be called directly without creating any instance. But, I don't see how can I use it to implement the solution that I mentioned above. Can you please elaborate a little bit?